# Google Maps API - Toggle Marker Visibility

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**How do I toggle the visibility of a subset of markers in Google Maps API?**

I have two sets of marker location data. Want to add a button to toggle visibility of each set independently.

Full code below for convenience. I have a button code in the header.

```
<button onclick="toggleMELocations()">Toggle ME Locations</button>`
```

The button is showing up, but clicking does not yield the expected result (ME locations disappearing).

The relevant function is "toggleMELocations." I am trying to say that if ME locations are currently visible, make them invisible. And vice versa.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
var map;

function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 4,
center: {
  lat: 40,
  lng: -95
},
styles: [{
  stylers: [{
    saturation: -100
  }]
}]
});

setMarkers(map);
}

function toggleMELocations() {
if (MEs) {
for (i in MEs) {
  var visibility = (MEs[i].getVisible() == true) ? false : true;
  MEs[i].setVisible(visibility);
  }
 }
}

// MEC locations
var MEs = [
['aaa', 36.07, -75.79],
['bbb', 40.07, -83.79]
];

// CC locations
var Concentras = [
['xxx', 38.01, -75.55],
['yyy', 30.10, -90.3]
];

function setMarkers(map) {
 // Adds markers to the map.

 for (var i = 0; i < MEs.length; i++) {
 var ME = MEs[i];
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {
    lat: ME[1],
    lng: ME[2]
  },
  icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
  map: map,
  title: ME[0]

});
}

for (var i = 0; i < Concentras.length; i++) {
var Concentra = Concentras[i];
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {
    lat: Concentra[1],
    lng: Concentra[2]
  },
  icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png',
  map: map,
  title: Concentra[0]

});
 }
 }
```

Comment: Edit: Tried replacing "toggleMELocations" code with the following:   `function toggleMELocations() {
  for (var i = 0; i < MEs.length; i++) {
    var ME = MEs[i];
    if (!ME.getVisible()) {
      ME.setVisible(true);
    } else {
      ME.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
} `    Still no dice. Per debugger, getting message that ME.getVisible is not a function at toggleMELocations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly `getVisible()` is not a valid function.

You need to add a global variable defined: `var addedMEs = [];`
This acts as an array of markers that have been added to the map in the `setMarkers` method. We change the `setMarkers` method to include a line which will add a `marker` **object** to the array defined above:

```
for (var i = 0; i < MEs.length; i++) {
    var ME = MEs[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: ME[1],
        lng: ME[2]
      },
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
      map: map,
      title: ME[0]

    });
    addedMEs.push(marker);
  }
```

Then we need to remove the `getVisible()` method as it is invalid. we change this line to:

```
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var visibility = (bounds.contains(addedMEs[i].position) == true) ? false : true;
  addedMEs[i].setVisible(visibility);
```

And it works. :]

Here is the JSFiddle to try: **https://jsfiddle.net/cmjcs5eL/13/**

Comment: Thanks John! I ended up keeping the get.Visible method (which works as long as you have the market object as you described). For others in the future who are new like me - the problem was that I was asking the program to check if markers were visible on the map. However, I was checking against the marker inputs (my MEs var coordinates) instead of an actual marker on the map. You need to check against the array of actual markers as John described.